# No authorizations to perform actions - but the app is authorized

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I would like to use restfb to post to one of my pages. I want to post as the page itself, not as an user posting to the page's wall.

This is the code I'm using:

```
public class App {
    //user token for accessing the page as admin
    private static final String INITIAL_ACCESS_TOKEN = "#";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        restfb();
    }

    public static void restfb() throws Exception {
        DefaultFacebookClient fbClient;
        Connection myAccounts;
        fbClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(INITIAL_ACCESS_TOKEN, Version.VERSION_2_5);
        myAccounts = fbClient.fetchConnection("me/accounts", Account.class);
        String pageToken = null;
        //retrieve the page token
        for(Object a : myAccounts.getData()) {
            Account account = (Account)a;
            if("MyPage".equals(account.getName())) {
                pageToken = account.getAccessToken();
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(pageToken); //not null here

        //post to the page
        fbClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(pageToken, Version.VERSION_2_5);
        //"me" should refer to the page itself..?
        fbClient.publish("me/feed", FacebookType.class, Parameter.with("message", "Aloha! ;)"));
    }
}
```

I get error

> Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action (code 200, subcode null)

I already visited this url:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=###&redirect_uri=###&scope=manage_pages,publish_actions,user_actions:pagealias&response_type=code
```

It asked me to give permissions to my app to post and manage my pages, and I granted them.

The application is not public, as it is a test application I want to use for development (so I didn't ask for the Review).

What am I missing? Which other permission does the app need in order to work and properly post?

Answer (score 0):

You should request the `publish_pages` permission to post as page.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-publish_pages